# Как установить тему в Designer окне по умолчанию?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Когда открываю `layout` в дизайнере то по умолчанию стоит тема `"DefaultTheme"`
Она черная, а я хочу белую (`Theme.AppCompat.Light`)

Если установлю белую, то все ОК. Но как только переключюсь в xml-вид, внесу изменений и сохраняю, то в дизайнере снова выходит черная тема.

Это сильно раздражает.

Как решить эту проблему?

PS. Проблема именно в дизайнере, так то в эмуляторе выходит белая тема. Поэтому неудобно при каждом сохрании искать тему в выпадающем списке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне кажется это какойто глюк, xamarin вообще один большой глюк, попробую протестить на новом проекте